# Drupal: Autocomplete Nodereference Search That Contains Any Word

Tags: drupal, search, autocomplete, cck

If a node's title is "foo bar magic" i would like it to show up inside the nodereference-autocompletion field, even when the user inputs "foo magic". How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6...

When configuring your node reference field with auto complete widget, make sure the 'Autocomplete matching' option is set to 'Contains' rather than 'Starts with'.